# Characters problem since kernel and graphic update

Tags: 14.04, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics

I have this annoying issue since yesterday when I updated my kernel and graphics. I have a Dell xps 13 2015 running ubuntu 14.04.

It doesn't happen all the time, it can happen in any program, including nautilus.

Thank you,

Michael

[image: graphic problem]

Comment: Try to clear font cache with: `fc-cache -rv`

Comment: It didn't fixed it instantly but after relaunching programs it seems to be solved. I wait a little to be sure and I mark it as solved. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear font cache with:

```
fc-cache -rv
```

After that, reboot the computer to reinitialize the softwares.